# Why do we need the FIN flag in TCP?

Tags: tcp, syn

The SYN bit could stay 1 after the connection is established and then changing it back to 0 would signal the same as FIN does?

The only reason I could think of why FIN is needed is if SYN is used during the connection, but I haven't found anything suggesting that.

Comment: This is not a programming question, i.e. off-topic here. It is more appropriate at [networkengineering.se].

Comment: Well, if you are programming an implementation of TCP you need to know how it works... But to be honest I did now that Network Engineering existed - so thank you for the tip :)

Comment: @AllanHelboe if you were programming your own TCP implementation, you would have to follow the TCP spec, and the spec says to use `FIN`.  So asking *WHY* `FIN` is used would still be off-topic as the answer would simply be "because the spec says so".